# update redis data based on daily extract from mysql

Tags: redis

I was wondering what good practices I should follow to update redis persistent data based on a daily extract I've got from my centralized db.

Everyday I've got a json extract of name from a mysql db. 
I want to update redis data based on this extract  :

day 1: 
name A 
name B
name C

day 2: 
name A 
name B' 
name D

so here, I would like to update B, remove C and add D.

I would like to know if redis has a specific way to achieve it or should I compare my 2 lists to highlight what add/delete/update I have to perform.

thanks a lot !

gab

Comment: Why don't you give one day TTL to keys, and just add new values without checking if exists.

Comment: Hi @Emre, thanks for your answer, I've been thinking of TTL but I was worries my keys might not be accessible for a time... I'll keep digging.

Comment: Did you consider using ReJSON? https://oss.redislabs.com/rejson/

Comment: at the end I'm doing the following : I'm listening to DB event, and trigger pubsub from kafka with different attribute : add/update/delete + my data in the message, to a container that is doing the etl + function add/update/delete